# Are Spark Streaming RDDs always processed in order?

Tags: spark-streaming

I'm writing a Spark Streaming application that uses RabbitMQ to consume events. One feature of RabbitMQ that I intend to make use of is bulk ack of messages, i.e. no need to ack one-by-one, but only ack the last event in a batch and that would ack the entire batch.

Before I commit to doing so, I'd like to know if Spark Streaming always processes RDDs in the same order they arrive in, i.e. if RDD1 arrives before RDD2, is it true that RDD2 will never be scheduled/processed before RDD1 is finished?

This is crucial to the ack logic, since if RDD2 can be potentially processed while RDD1 is still being processed, then if I ack the the last event in RDD2 that would also ack all events in RDD1, even though they may have not been completely processed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, only after all the retries etc related to batch X is done, then batch X+1 will be started.
[ref](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201506.mbox/%3cCA+AHuKnFsLw+y=U5eeYpfMXAEnthP7zdZ2zUj2z2qf1=sZUZ7w@mail.gmail.com%3e)

Additional information: This is true in the default configuration. You may
find references to an undocumented hidden configuration called
`spark.streaming.concurrentJobs` elsewhere in the mailing list. Setting
that to more than 1 to get more concurrency (between output ops) breaks
the above guarantee. 
[ref](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-user/201507.mbox/%3cCA+AHuKkbkTgR457AKKBJTFUDtfMPuXUFq0GSLSp213XHUmsYaA@mail.gmail.com%3e)

Comment: Thanks @michal-Čizmazia. It's been a while, but I arrived at the same conclusion based on the mailing list posts you referenced. I probably should've posted an answer to my own question here at the time. Thanks.